# PHP PDO WHERE field = json?

Tags: php, json, pdo

**Hello.**

So I'm doing the article submission atm and I need articles to have multiple categories... Article categories would be stored in `articles` table under `categories` field like this `{"cat1","cat2","cat3"}`.  But a mind popped to my head... "What if I want to lookup articles by a category?". If I would do something like `SELECT * FROM articles WHERE categories = ?` then I can't define what categories which post has... So I can't lookup by a  category this way. Any suggestions, solutions? Much appreaciated!

**Edit:** If I would retrieve all post from database and do some for each solution it would cause server loads or even crashes for several minutes. Right now I have **7,307** articles.

Comment: i asume you have a table "articles" and a table "categories" - then the solution is a so called n-m-relation. meaning: a table with two colums: one references the article, the other the category. then you can select whatever you want with a simple join.

Comment: Look at a Basic Database Design book or tutorial. This is basically chapter 2 so not rocket science

Comment: You should look into [Database Normalization](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/). (That's what the other comments are suggesting.)

Comment: That's not a bad idea actually. I already have a table "categories" in which each category is defined. So I would do something like: "article_categories". So that would need like a 3 fields: id, article_id, categorie.

Comment: ^ Yepp, that's the way to go.. (assuming you meant `category_id` as the last field).

Comment: Yes, Magnus. By cateogry name would'nt get me far, If I would change category name in the future. Always only id's if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve your actual problem, you can use this sql query

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE categories LIKE '%cat1%'
```

But, about database scheme, Best way should like to have `articles` `categories` and a pivot table `article_categories` table. A many to many relation would help

### articles

id,
title
...

### categories

id,
name, ...

### article_categories

id,
article_id,
category_id